# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. using vuejs and express

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vuejs2, cors

please i keep getting this error in my vue code

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/api/chats' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

this is how i use cors

```
const cors = require("cors");
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  }
});
app.use(cors());
```

this my front end in vue

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  mounted() {   
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/chats",{
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

please how can i fix this cause i dont know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Why do you not use `{ origin: "*" }` inside `app.use(cors());`?

Comment: @Geshode i'm getting same error

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the code like this. That's worked for me

```
var server = app.listen(8001);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    }
});
```

Comment: have all this in my code

Comment: Is this the order ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a proxy in your VUE project, to resolve the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` issue.

In your `vue.config.js` file, add code:

```
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  overlay: {
    warnings: false,
    errors: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/dev-api': {
      target: 'http://localhost: 3001',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/api' }
    }
  }
}
```